# working with images that may not be big enough for the width of wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a page design that looks like this:

[image]

The image comes from an external source and I have no control over the dimensions. Is there a way that I can make it fill the correct space without it zooming in?

The current problem I am having:

[image]

The actual image looks like this:

[image]

The image is wrapped in a div that has a max-height set:

`.item { max-height:700px; }`

and the image has the following CSS:

`.item img {width:100%; height:100%; object-fit:cover;}`

I am obviously doing something wrong. Is there a way to get image to show at the proportions of its parent without looking warped, or zoomed in?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. If we can't "zoom in" (stretch the image), what are you expecting? Can you create a snippet so we can see the problem?

Comment: What part of the aspect ratio is larger, have you tried only making its size 100%?

Comment: Given the image can have any aspect ratio is there any alternative to using contain?